# ASP.NET Pages with inline code running slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, caching

I have developed a website that allows the user to create dictionaries for different languages. Most of my pages will call a helper method that gets the current language ID and then returns some text based on the label that is called. Here is an example of the call:

```
<%= BasePage.GetStringValue(LanguageEntityTypes.AdministratorMenu, "Menu Jobs") %>
```

The helper method will then retrieve the text from the cache (using standard System.Web.Caching) which was built on application startup and held in memory.

The problem I am getting is that anything that uses this inline method loads after the rest of the page. So on a specific page I have a menu, all of which use the method to display the text. This text is only displayed several seconds after the rest of the page has loaded.

I'm wondering whether this is because of the lack of RAM in the server (it's running on a micro EC2 instance) or whether there is some flawed design here.

To note, when I use a local dev machine there is no delay.

Comment: Are you looking at the same database from the dev machine and the actual server? The real database may just have a lot more data in it.

Comment: Entire page html would be served to the client at one time (or say sequentially if its huge) - so its unlikely that rest of page (or the content after the problematic code) gets displayed first while the menu takes time. There may be something else going on here - such as some java-script loading things dynamically using AJAX etc. Perhaps you should check about the menu and how it is rendered etc